# sqldump somehow looks for a table instead of full backup?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple BAT file that I want to run at times to take backups of two local development MySQL databases.

The file name should be "testdb1-Fri 6/6/2018 194233.sql" for example. However, my BAT script is making mysqldump look for a table called 6/6/2018 somehow? Script below, and screenshot of error.

```
@ECHO OFF
set filename=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -proot -hlocalhost cadsys > C:\temp\testdb1-%filename%.sql
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -proot -hlocalhost comm1 > C:\temp\testdb-%filename%.sql

pause
cls
exit
```

[image: BAT file error]
Any pointers?

Comment: Did you read the question?

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes around the suggested filename, the spaces within the filename are interpreted by mysqldump as seperate commands

```
set filename="%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"
```